# Dynamically find out how many inputs a function has, Racket

Tags: scheme, racket, arity

Is there a way to find out at runtime, how many inputs (arguments, parameters) a function has?

Say, I want to:

```
(define (my-function unknown-function)
  ...
  (number-of-necessary-arguments unknown-function)
  ...)
```

Comment: Don't you need "apply" actually?

Answer (score 12, accepted):

You can use `procedure-arity`.

```
(procedure-arity expt)                     ; => 2
```

Note that when using `procedure-arity` with variadic functions or `case-lambda` or the like, the results are more complicated:

```
(procedure-arity apply)                    ; => (arity-at-least 2)
(procedure-arity (case-lambda
                  ((x) x)
                  ((x y z) z)
                  ((a b c d e f . g) g)))  ; => `(1 3 ,(arity-at-least 6))
```